# Cordova Electron Builder Icon Packaged Wrong on Linux

Tags: linux, icons, packages, deb, apache-cordova

When building a Cordova app for Electron on Linux, the icon file in `platforms/electron/build-res` has the improper name `installer.png`. ([The Linux configuration page](https://www.electron.build/configuration/linux#LinuxConfiguration-target) says `The icon filename must contain the size (e.g. 32x32.png) of the icon.`)
This is causing the icon file in the resulting package to be under `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/0x0`, and thus not showing correctly in the desktop environment. The name doesn't seem to change no matter what attributes I put on the `icon` element in the `<platform name="electron">` element in `config.xml`, and even if I manually rename the icon to `512x512.png`, edit `platforms/electron/build/builder-effective-config.yaml`, and manually invoke `electron builder`, the icon is still placed under `0x0`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by [this line of code](https://github.com/develar/app-builder/blob/1cceb8fd6fe68955cecb96fb48259087980cd826/pkg/icons/icon-converter.go#L187) in [App Builder](https://github.com/develar/app-builder), so for now the solution must be to clone App Builder, edit that line to export the correct size data, build it, and put it as `node_modules/app-builder-bin`, replacing [the original one from NPM](https://npmjs.com/app-builder-bin). I really don't understand why it doesn't work normally, but this solves the problem.